# Is there a way to decompress the NTFS compression under another operating system?

Tags: ntfs

As mentioned above: I would like to decompress the NTFS compression, but not under Windows, as it's using some files. Or is there any other way to decompress all files?

I already have a quite old Ubuntu(14.04) on the PC or could install any Linux on a USB flash drive.

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux NTFS-3G driver should be able to handle the compression.
But you will need a copy utility that is aware of the compression and activates that for the files/folders being copied that need to be compressed.
And that is the problem: I'm not aware of any copy-utility in Linux that reliably knows how to do that.

If you are just trying to clone the Windows system to a bigger (or faster) disk please consider really cloning the disk image itself.
That is WAY safer and less error-prone. And if the new disk is bigger you can simply resize the NTFS partition afterwards (either from Linux or from WIndows).

Comment: Is it also able to permanently decompress the files and remove the compression flag?

I want to decompress the files for performance reasons.

Comment: Decompress the original when it is copied somewhere else? YES. Removing the compression flag? I don't know.  But I wonder why you think that removing compression on system files would gain noticable performance benefits. The system-files that Windows compresses are typically rarely used. Or only read once at startup. Benefits are neglectable, unless you have an ancient CPU (without hardware acceleration for compression), but that would barely run Windows anyway. And there is a big chance that the next Windows Update will revert your chances, making all your work pointless.

Comment: The point is: I'm not talking about system files. I've compressed the whole drive!